# HTML - CSS - Responsive same size Image grid with appearing box when hover

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, image

I am trying to create an image grid that when each image is hovered a box with links appears on that image.

So far I have made the grid responsive however, I am finding hard to show a box to each image when I hover it with the pointer.

The Image below explains it better:

[image]

Any Help?

HTML:

```
<?php
$arrayImg = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 , 9 , 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
?>

  <div id="pattern" class="pattern">
    <ul class="g">

  <?php foreach ($arrayImg as $offerV) { ?>

            <li>
                <img class="offerImg" src="https://images.hertz.com/content/US/exceptions/SunnyRoad_600x225.jpg" alt="Product Name" />
                <div class="offerSocial"><div>
            </li>

    <?php } ?>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
<style>

        .offerImg {
            -webkit-transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
            -ms-transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
            transition:  550ms ease-in-out;
        }
        .offerImg:hover {

            filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
            -webkit-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
            -moz-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
            -o-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
            -ms-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
        }

        .offerSocial{
            width: 100%;
              height: 100%;
              position: relative;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

        }

        .g {
            position: relative;
            padding: 0.25em;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: 100%;
            left: -50px;
        }
        .g li {
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0.25em;
            list-style-type: none;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        .g img {
            display: block;
        }
        .g li:nth-child(odd) {
            clear: left;
        }



        @media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
            .g li {
                width: 33.3333333333333333%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(odd) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 55em) {
            .g li {
                width: 33.3333333333333333%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(odd) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 72em) {
            .g li {
                width: 33.3333333333333333%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(odd) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (min-width: 90em) {
            .g li {
                width: 33.3333333333333333%; 
            }
            .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
                clear: left;
            }
            .g li:nth-child(odd) {
                clear: none;
            }
        }
</style>
```

Comment: Isn't there a part of the code missing? When I paste it in a codepen, it doesn't work at all...

Comment: It does not work maybe because codepen does not recognise php ?

Comment: I removed the php and copied the <li> multiple times.

Comment: So maybe because it's embed in WordPress template.  But my code it's all there..

Comment: Check it out: http://codepen.io/thomasbormans/pen/XbGdYM

Comment: Yep something is wrong. Got part of the code here: http://codepen.io/bradfrost/pen/xkcBn

Comment: I had to change some of the values to fit on my wp template

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85510/discussion-between-thomasbormans-and-snos).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are after. You have to set the `li` wrappers to `position:relative` and position the overlay absolutely.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.offerImg {
  -webkit-transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
  transition: 550ms ease-in-out;
}

.offerImg:hover {
  filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
}

.offerSocial {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  transform: translateY(100%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

li:hover .offerSocial {
  transform: translateY(0%);
  opacity: 1;
}

.g {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.g li {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 0.25em;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.g img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.g li:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 40em) {
  .g li {
    width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  }
  .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .g li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 55em) {
  .g li {
    width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  }
  .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .g li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 72em) {
  .g li {
    width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  }
  .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .g li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: none;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 90em) {
  .g li {
    width: 33.3333333333333333%;
  }
  .g li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: left;
  }
  .g li:nth-child(odd) {
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="pattern" class="pattern">
  <ul class="g">
    <li>
      <img class="offerImg" src="https://images.hertz.com/content/US/exceptions/SunnyRoad_600x225.jpg" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
        <div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="offerImg" src="https://images.hertz.com/content/US/exceptions/SunnyRoad_600x225.jpg" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
        <div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="offerImg" src="https://images.hertz.com/content/US/exceptions/SunnyRoad_600x225.jpg" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
        <div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="offerImg" src="https://images.hertz.com/content/US/exceptions/SunnyRoad_600x225.jpg" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
        <div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="offerImg" src="https://images.hertz.com/content/US/exceptions/SunnyRoad_600x225.jpg" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
        <div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="offerImg" src="https://images.hertz.com/content/US/exceptions/SunnyRoad_600x225.jpg" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
        <div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img class="offerImg" src="https://images.hertz.com/content/US/exceptions/SunnyRoad_600x225.jpg" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
        <div>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/qdvZQx)

Comment: Thank you this works. Now I will try to added it to my work.

Comment: @PaulieD where does he add the links to the overlay??

Comment: It's just a div...the links woud go in the div

Comment: works good thanks! Is there a way to have the img effect visible when the box is hovered? i am trying using                                   .offerSocial:hover > .offerImg {
  filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
  -webkit-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: blur(1px) grayscale(100%);
}

Comment: You can't affect the image by hovering on the overlay becuase of the structure. You could have the blur come in when you hover the list item - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/pJYyME